# setTimeout to delay change on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

When the right button is held down the `herocolor` changes to green (this already works), but I added a setTimeout so that after 1 second (while the button is still being held down) `herocolor` will become blue (this does not work). When the button is released it does turn back to red as expected.

My goal is to make the color toggle back and forth between green and blue every 1 second.

The alert properly delays and properly updates `herocolor` to blue but the square does not turn blue. I am utterly mystified why this isn't working.

```
loop = function() {

  var herocolor = "#ff0000";
  if (controller.right == true){
     herocolor = "#00ff00";
    setTimeout(function(){
      herocolor = "#0000ff";
      alert(herocolor);
    }, 1000);
  }

  context.fillStyle = "#202020";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
  context.fillStyle = herocolor;
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(hero.x, hero.y, hero.width, hero.height);
  context.fill();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
```

COMPLETE CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
body {
  align-content:space-around;
  background-color:#202830;
  color:#ffffff;
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center;
}
canvas {
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas></canvas>
<script>
var context, controller, hero, loop;
context = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");
context.canvas.height = 400;
context.canvas.width = 800;
hero = {
  height:40,
  width:40,
  x:144,
  y:140,
};
controller = {
  right:false,
  up:false,
  keyListener:function(event) {
    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown")?true:false;
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 39:
        controller.right = key_state;
      break;
    }
  }
};
loop = function() {

  var herocolor = "#ff0000";
  if (controller.right == true){
     herocolor = "#00ff00";
    setTimeout(function(){
      herocolor = "#0000ff";
      alert(herocolor);
    }, 1000);
  }

  context.fillStyle = "#202020";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
  context.fillStyle = herocolor;
  context.beginPath();
  context.rect(hero.x, hero.y, hero.width, hero.height);
  context.fill();

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener)
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your loop 1. sets herocolor to green 2. draws a green rectangle 3. sets herocolor to blue after a delay of 1 second. This happens about 60 times per second. You need to move the herocolor declaration outside your loop function.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/12an643t/ (the basic idea is to count how long the right key has been held down and determine the color based on that; this requires storing the color in a global variable) I'm guessing this is ultimately about animating a walk-cycle for the hero?

Answer (score 0):

Please take reference from the below sample code, here I am creating a simple line using canvas and displaying after 3 sec using `setTimeout`:

```js
var canvas = $("#myCanvas")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var amount = 0;
var startX = 164;
var startY = 120;
var endX = 1094;
var endY = 120;

setTimeout(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        amount += 0.01; // change to alter duration
        if (amount > 1) {
            amount = 1;
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        c.strokeStyle = "black";
        c.lineWidth=1;
        c.strokeStyle="#707070";
        c.moveTo(startX, startY);
        // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
        c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
        c.stroke();
    }, 0);

}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1250" height="120"></canvas>
```